# Make sure my app is on after factory reset

Tags: applications, factory-reset

I'm making an app that I intend to put onto a bunch of tablets before giving them away in a give away. However obviously the people who get the tablet will use there google accounts, so is there anyway to get the app to be on the tablet after it is factory reset?

Comment: The only way to ensure that an app "survives" a factory reset would be to install it in the system partition, which requires root privileges, or you to make your own ROM.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman What if the phone gets a system update?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab If you modify the system partition or install your own ROM, it typically will no longer be *able* to receive system updates.